# VirtualBox не открывает образ жесткого диска

Tags: virtualbox

Хочу через виртуалку поставить `Windows 10 Creators Update` на физический жесткий диск.
Сделал его образ `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename drive.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda`, но при попытке его подключения к виртуалке VBox ругается, что не хватат прав:
Не удалось открыть образ виртуального диска /home/sm4ll_3gg/VirtualBox VMs/drive.vmdk.

> Permission problem accessing the file for the medium
>   '/home/sm4ll_3gg/VirtualBox VMs/drive.vmdk' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).
>
> Код ошибки: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004) Компонент: MediumWrap
>   Интерфейс: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} Вызванный
>   интерфейс: IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} Код
>   ошибки метода: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)

Сделал владельцем этого файла себя и группу `vboxusers`, выдал права `777` через chmod, ребутнулся. Ничего не помогает.

```
ls -l drive.vmdk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sm4ll_3gg vboxusers 538 апр 30 12:49 drive.vmdk
```

ОС: `openSUSE 42.2`
Что с этим делать? В гугле ничего внятного не нашел

Answer (score 2):

Нужно запустить сам VirtualBox с админскими правами:

```
sudo VirtualBox
```

Due to the nature of having raw disk access, you must start VirtualBox with admin rights.

Source: https://scottlinux.com/2010/06/26/raw-disk-access-with-virtualbox/

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ,  попробовал через [вот этот ответ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284704/verr-access-denied-when-trying-to-add-a-raw-disk-to-virtual-box)  Увы он меня завёл в тупик. А ваш вывел :3