# VirtualBox не запускает образ виртуального диска

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Попробовал запустить в Ubuntu через VirtualBox образ виртуального диска ( c debian 9) backup-mmcblk1.vdi выдавал ошибку :

> Permission problem accessing the file for the medium '/home/comp/backup-mmcblk1.vdi' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).
>
> Код ошибки: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004) Компонент: MediumWrap Интерфейс: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} Вызванный
>   интерфейс: IVirtualBox {9570b9d5-f1a1-448a-10c5-e12f5285adad} Код
>   ошибки метода: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)

Посмотрел [вот этот вопрос](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284704/verr-access-denied-when-trying-to-add-a-raw-disk-to-virtual-box). Попробовал так как там пишут.

Вызвал команды (имя моего компа comp):

```
comp@comp0:~$ sudo usermod -a -G disk comp
comp@comp0:~$ sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers comp
```

В общем :( не сработало , та же самая ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно запустить сам VirtualBox с правами администратора:

```
sudo VirtualBox
```

[Due to the nature of having raw disk access, you must start VirtualBox with admin rights.](https://scottlinux.com/2010/06/26/raw-disk-access-with-virtualbox/)

---

*По сути это "частный" случай, [вот этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660241/virtualbox-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0). НО у вы не разрешили его "дописать" (отредактировать).*